# Nextjs not showing fetched data from strapi

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, strapi, next.js13

I am working with Strapi and NextJS 14+ and I have successfully fetched data from Strapi with its API but I am not able to fetch data in the NEXTJS application.

Here is my code from

file path => post/[slug]/page.js

```
const getPost = async (id) => {
  const data = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/posts?filters[Permalink][$eq]=${id}`);
  const post = await data.json();

  return post;
};


/*export const generateStaticParams = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/posts")
    // const data = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/posts?filters[Permalink][$eq]=my-first-post")
    const posts = await data.json()
  
    return posts.data.map(post => ({
      params: {
        slug: post.attributes.permalink
      }
      
    }))
  }*/


  export default async function Home({ params: { slug } }) {

    const post = await getPost(slug)

    
    return (
        <>

        <div id={post.id}></div>
        
        
        <ul>
        {post.data.map(item => (
            <>
            <li key={item.id}>{item.attributes.Title}</li>
            </>
        ))}
        </ul>


        </>
    )
}
```

**MY STRAPI API DATA**

Below is my API DATA Generated by Strapi and fetched from Postman

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "Title": "My Second Post",
                "Meta_Description": "Some Description",
                "Content": "Some Text",
                "createdAt": "2023-11-27T14:42:07.787Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-11-27T14:50:16.707Z",
                "publishedAt": "2023-11-27T14:42:29.807Z",
                "Block_editor": null,
                "Permalink": "my-second-post"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have tested the code with https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts with some changes and its working successfully

***NOTE:- I am using Next JS - APP Directory***

Comment: Might just be a typo but looking at your response data; Shouldn't `post.attributes.permalink` actually be `post.attributes.Permalink`?

Comment: @FabioNettis  thank you for your reply just want to tell you that you can ignore that  generateStaticParams as it not doing anything here. You know what let me comment that code